# Отображение сообщения пришедшего через Firebase Cloud Messaging в activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, fcm

Делаю месенджер.
У меня есть активность с recyclerView, который содержит переписку (сообщения обоих пользователей).
Обмен сообщениями происходит посредством FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).
После отправки сообщения получаю его клиентом с помощью следующего кода:

```
class FCMReceiver : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
        Log.d("Response","message: ${message.data["message"]}")
    }
}
```

Сообщение приходит как надо.
И так, вопрос: **Как отобразить пришедшее сообщение в моем RecyclerView, после того, как я его получил?**

Пробовал:

Вынести экземпляр активности в статик поле этой же активности, и потом использовать это поле, что бы получить доступ к recyclerView с класса-получателя FCMReceiver.

```
class FCMReceiver : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
        Log.d("Response","message: ${message.data["message"]}")
        ChatActivity.activity.pushMessage(message)
    }
}
```

Выдает:

```
CalledFromWrongThreadException:
    Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Если кто то знает как это правильно делается (возможно я делаю совсем не так как надо), прошу помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел следующий ответ:
Можно отправить Broadcast сообщение
В классе, который наследуется от FirebaseMessagingService (класс-получатель сообщений):

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString("msgBody", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

      Intent new_intent = new Intent();
      new_intent.setAction("ACTION_STRING_ACTIVITY");
      new_intent.putExtra("msg", bundle);

      sendBroadcast(new_intent);

      //other code
    }
```

В активности, где будем перехватывать наш BroadCast:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BroadcastReceiver activityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("msg");
            String message = bundle.getString("msgBody");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        if (activityReceiver != null) {
           IntentFilter intentFilter = new  IntentFilter("ACTION_STRING_ACTIVITY");
           registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
    }
}
```

[ИСТОЧНИК](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486172/how-to-display-message-of-push-notification-from-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-tex)

Comment: Все верно, только не забывайте вовремя отписываться через `unregisterReceiver`, чтобы не было неожиданностей.

Comment: Зачем отписываться в данном случае? Создалась активность переписки, и все время пока она работает надо отлавливать. Хотя.. стоит ли отписываться и опять подписываться когда активность уходит в фон (pause) либо stop. Будет ли отлавливаться бродкаст когда активность в фоне?

Comment: Вот именно, в вашем случае ресивер будет получать сообщения, пока система не убьет активити совсем. Она может находиться в состоянии "destroyed" и все еще получать сообщения.

Comment: Вот что на офф сайте пишут: `Be mindful of where you register and unregister the receiver, for example, if you register a receiver in onCreate(Bundle) using the activity's context, you should unregister it in onDestroy() to prevent leaking the receiver out of the activity context. If you register a receiver in onResume(), you should unregister it in onPause() to prevent registering it multiple times (If you don't want to receive broadcasts when paused, and this can cut down on unnecessary system overhead).` https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts